# Google's Places API gives off results - what can I do to get more accurate results with lat and lng?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-geolocation

Using Google maps api, I am trying to get information at a coffee shop I am at (for example).

On [google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Thunderbird+Coffee/@30.2844076,-97.7215898,17z/data=!4m12!1m6!3m5!1s0x8644b5ecb62554d9:0xa0253da9930f1b2a!2sThunderbird+Coffee!8m2!3d30.2843817!4d-97.7193844!3m4!1s0x8644b5ecb62554d9:0xa0253da9930f1b2a!8m2!3d30.2843817!4d-97.7193844),  it shows `30.28456,-97.71936`

[image]

In the [Place IDs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/place-id) api, I consume the api with `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=****&location=30.28456,-97.71936&radius=20`

The first issue is that I have to use at least a radius 20m, if I go any smaller it will not include the Thunderbird Coffee Shop. This means with a radius of 20m, I also get other locations that I am not looking for.

The second issue is, the location lat and lng are not the same in the returned output below for Thunderbird Coffee Shop. The returned snippet shows `30.284403, -97.7194011` while Google maps shows  `30.28456,-97.71936`.

Why are the results so off? Is there something I can do differently to get a more accurate reading of the place I am at with Googles geolocation apis? I am using lat and lng because I get that from the browser in my web app.

```js
        {
          "business_status": "OPERATIONAL",
          "geometry": {
            "location": {
              "lat": 30.284403,
              "lng": -97.7194011
            },
            "viewport": {
              "northeast": {
                "lat": 30.2856802802915,
                "lng": -97.71801381970849
              },
              "southwest": {
                "lat": 30.2829823197085,
                "lng": -97.7207117802915
              }
            }
          },
          "icon": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v1/png_71/restaurant-71.png",  
          "icon_background_color": "#FF9E67",
          "icon_mask_base_uri": "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/v2/restaurant_pinlet",
          "name": "Thunderbird Coffee",
          "opening_hours": {
            "open_now": true
          },
          "photos": [
            { 
              "height": 1536,
              "html_attributions": [
                "<a href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/100343333546892327834\">Roy Gutierrez</a>"
              ],
              "photo_reference": "AcYSjRgYToIRiy6i83ZoEP-9-ps2rTFEWoryr52r03LzaHYQ-nJiRm6ho24ut_LNNdKDx551awteSNyfXP_HmbMFvJtzuRirXhCAE4lX1X1CjfGhuNtNoTvxaF6mFyxCHGWQwiuOEIutxahOqWMaoSSCMRra6I4z8_jrMEtkdatQuX6Kq1ml",
              "width": 2048
            }
          ],
          "place_id": "ChIJ2VQltuy1RIYRKhsPk6k9JaA",
          "plus_code": {
            "compound_code": "77MJ+Q6 Austin, TX, USA",
            "global_code": "862477MJ+Q6"
          },
          "price_level": 1,
          "rating": 4.5,
          "reference": "ChIJ2VQltuy1RIYRKhsPk6k9JaA",
          "scope": "GOOGLE",
          "types": [
            "restaurant",
            "cafe",
            "store",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
          ],
          "user_ratings_total": 676,
          "vicinity": "2200 Manor Road, Austin"
        },
```

Comment: You should contact Google Map's Technical Support or file a bug on [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/) so that they can investigate a little further as this could be an internal issue.

Comment: I checked the coordinates `30.28456,-97.71936` with the geocoder and noticed that you gave a wrong coordinate. This one is from another building beside it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that in your first issue, you just wanted to know how to search for the place details with greater than 20 search radius and still return the result you want. And the second one is that you want to know how is the API result different from the Tactile Map.

For your issue #1, I will include it in my explanation later but your issue #2 seems to be just an error on your part. The coordinates `30.28456, -97.71936` is not what the Google Maps showed as a location of the "Thunder Bird Coffee". I don't know how you got this value, but this is the coordinates from the building beside it. The actual coordinates of the Marker that points to the coffee shop is actually `30.284382,-97.719384`.

[image: Coordinates comparison1]

To investigate further, I tried to use the [Nearby Search of Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby#nearby-search-example).

I used these parameters: `location=30.28456,-97.71936`(I even used the wrong one you gave), `radius=100`(referring to your issue #1), and `type=cafe`(to avoid issue #1 of including places you don't want on your result).

Here's the actual request if you wanna check it out yourself(Use your own API Key): `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?&location=30.28456,-97.71936&radius=100&type=cafe&key=API_KEY`

Then here's the result I got:

[image]

The resulting coordinates of Google Maps and Nearby Search was within the premise of the right building.

***"Note: Google Maps and Google Maps Platform are different products, so you should set your expectation that not all results would perfectly be the same but they would be pretty close"***

[image: Coordinates comparison2]

Now, both of these have the same Place ID for the Thunderbird coffee shop and I believe this is working as intended and is accurate as it can get to help you in using Geolocation API.

Hope this helps. Please feel free to comment if you need any more help.

Comment: The coordinates 30.28456, -97.71936 is indeed what the Google Maps showed as a location of the "Thunder Bird Coffee", I posted a screen shot in the original post to prove it. That was right clicking on the red map icon with the dropdown. So the second issue is still a issue.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying on how you got the coordinates. I was wondering how and where you got it. I tried as you have taught how to get the coordinates by right clicking on the marker and copied the coordinates to my clipboard, and surprisingly, I still got `30.284399099700533, -97.71938033054357`.

Comment: Can you try doing it again just to confirm?

Comment: The Google Maps seems fine on my end and was consistent with the API.

Comment: I just tried again... brought it up and right clicked on the red icon for the dropdown. It is showing `30.28460, -97.71939`. I will update the original post with the new screen shot

Comment: Please see https://imgur.com/Q4gOf3R

Comment: That's pretty weird. Everything seems fine on my end. But with all these, I'm assuming that what you'll be using would be the Maps API and not the Google Maps web App right? Let's just settle on my note on the answer that "Google Maps and Google Maps Platform are different products, so you should set your expectation that not all results would perfectly be the same but they would be pretty close". And since the API seems to work fine, I guess there's not much we could do here right?

Comment: The geolocation API would be dependent to the whole Google Maps Platform, regardless of the issues you face on the Google Maps web app. Because they are different platforms in the first place. As long as Google Maps Platform works as intended, you should have no problem with your app development.